# Problems outputing the location

Tags: java, android

I watched read some tutorials and followed one to make a app to get the location of the user but after I wrote it I had about 4 errors fixed 3 of them. Now the app started to launch but it either does not get the location or it doesn't output it. So here is my code. When I press the button nothing happens it doesn't crash or give out an error so I couldn't figure what was the problem.

Java

```
private Button button;
private TextView textView;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                textView.append("\n" +location.getLatitude() +""+location.getLongitude());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.INTERNET


            },10);


            return;
        }else{

        configureButton();

        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case 10:
            if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                configureButton();
            }
    }


private void configureButton() {

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 3000, 3, locationListener);
        }
    });
}
```

XML

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Coordinates: "
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</ScrollView>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Request Location"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollView2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You don't call `configureButton` for API 23 and up

Comment: so what can I do? (And I tried running it in api 21 and it didnt work)